# Is it possible to change the background behind the OS X login box screen saver unlock?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, security, screensaver

I have my Mac configured to require a password when it goes to sleep or when the screen saver comes on. When I wake it up I'm presented with a login box and the screen behind it is flat black. I would like to change or add a background to this unlock screen but I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm aware of how to [customize the background of the OS X startup login screen](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/22/customize-the-mac-os-x-login-screen/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no resource in `/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework`to change.

There is no mention of a wallpaper path in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist`, `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist` or `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.MachineID.plist`.

[Secrets.prefpane](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) doesn't have a setting.

Using `fs_usage` to see all disk paths accessed during locking and unlocking the machine via `Ctrl-Shift-Eject` yielded no unexpected disk accesses: No default wallpaper path, and all accessed `plist` preferences files (predominantly all variants of `.GlobalPreferences`, and surprisingly `com.apple.loginwindow`) mention any file path.

---

I conclude: It's very likely impossible.